# Items don't appear in listview c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, listview, controls

I created a listview using this:

```
SIZE size;
LVTILEVIEWINFO tileViewInfo;

hDLGlistb =CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW,L"",WS_HSCROLL|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD| 
          LVS_REPORT,5,80,450,130,ihDlg(HMENU)DLG_LIST_icons,0,0);              

size.cx=50;
size.cy=50;
tileViewInfo.cbSize   = sizeof(tileViewInfo);
tileViewInfo.dwFlags  = LVTVIF_FIXEDSIZE;
tileViewInfo.dwMask   = LVTVIM_COLUMNS | LVTVIM_TILESIZE;
tileViewInfo.cLines   = 2;
tileViewInfo.sizeTile = size;
ListView_SetTileViewInfo(hDLGlistb, &tileViewInfo);
```

Then I call this function to populate the list by icons from shell32.dll:

```
void iload_Icons(HWND hwndlist,LPTSTR pszfile)
{
  LVITEM lvItem;
  HIMAGELIST hSmall;
  HICON ic_index;
  HMODULE sh32 = LoadLibrary(pszfile);//TEXT("shell32.dll"));
  lvItem.mask = LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_STATE;
  lvItem.state = 0;
  lvItem.stateMask = 0;
  lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
  hSmall = ImageList_Create(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON),ILC_MASK, 1, 1); 
  for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
      ic_index = LoadIcon(sh32,MAKEINTRESOURCE(i));
      lvItem.iItem=i;
      lvItem.iImage=i;
      lvItem.pszText=pszfile;//not imoprtant
      lvItem.cchTextMax=100;
      ListView_InsertItem(hwndlist, &lvItem);
      ListView_SetItem(hwndlist,&lvItem);
      ImageList_AddIcon(hSmall, ic_index);               
    }
  ListView_SetImageList(hwndlist, hSmall, LVSIL_SMALL); 
  DestroyIcon(ic_index);
  FreeLibrary(sh32);
}
```

But when I run the application the list view is populated (because the vscroll bar is activated but I cannot see the items.

NOTE : the listview is a part of a dialog box and I call the `iload_icons()` function int the callback procedure of the dialog. I have yet to add code to handle events in the list.

Comment: The ImageList_Create call seems to be incorrect. You're passing "ILC_MASK" but you don't seem to be adding the bitmaps in pairs (a monochrome mask and a image bitmap). Another issue is that you are passing "1" as the initial number of images in the image list and "1" as the number of images that can be added to the image list, giving a total of 2 images, but you then try and add 20 images. Also, you are not checking the return values of any of your WinApi calls, so you don't know if they fail. For example, you don't check after you call "LoadIcon" to make sure "ic_index" is valid.

Comment: You need to add at least one column (using `ListView_InsertColumn`) to see anything in a listview. Also, you don't need to call `ListView_SetItem` immediately after `ListView_InsertItem`.

Comment: thank you, yes i added one column and i now can load the icons but they are loaded in low quality not like they are in windows dialog (folder menu personalize change icon) any idea why plz ?